# ActiveAdmin - how to customize edit action?

Tags: activeadmin

I have code :

ActiveAdmin.register MyTable do
controller do

```
def edit
  #---This code doesn't work
  render :template=>"myEditTemplate.html",:layout =>"active_admin"
end

def new
  #--code in this section works fine
  render :template=>"myNewTemplate.html",:layout =>"active_admin"
end
```

end

I want to see my edit template code under url like this:
http://***/admin/mytable/1/edit
BUT activeadmin doesn't see me my code/It shows code with own template not my
Why?

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6725233/active-admin-customize-only-new-form

Answer (score 8):

You should be able to do this via the `form` DSL method provided by ActiveAdmin. More details are in the [documentation for ActiveAdmin](http://activeadmin.info/docs/5-forms.html) and Formtastic.

Unfortunately, I don't believe ActiveAdmin nicely lets you have a completely different form rendered for `new` and `edit`. Using the partial rendering method in the documentation though you could conditionally change the form in the view based on `@object.persisted?`.

```rb
# app/admin/post.rb
ActiveAdmin.register Post do
  form :partial => "form"
end

# app/views/admin/post/_form.html.erb
<%= semantic_form_for [:admin, @post] do |f| %>
  <% if @post.persisted? %>
    Edit Form (Maybe rendered via a partial)
    <%= f.inputs :title, :body %>
    <%= f.buttons :commit %>
  <% else %>
    New Form
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Getting a forbidden attributes error when editing. Do you know why?

Comment: @BenMorganIO, Probabily you need to whitelist those params on your controller. Something like: `def model_params params.require(:model).permit(:attribute) end`

Answer (score 2):

You can render any view your like if you provide its full path to the render method. Something like that:

```
# app/admin/post.rb 
ActiveAdmin.register Post do  
    controller do
        def edit 
            render 'admin/posts/myEditTemplate', :layout =>"active_admin"
        end
        def new
            render 'admin/posts/myNewTemplate', :layout =>"active_admin"
        end
    end
end 

# app/views/admin/posts/myEditTemplate.html.erb
    # Your erb view for edit here
# app/views/admin/posts/myNewTemplate.html.erb
    # Your erb view for new here
```

Comment: I wanted two forms on the screen. For partials. This works great.. thanks.